# How much time does it take to increment one bit in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, design

In my lab I'm supposed to write a program in Verilog that makes a timer which outputs a tick every second. A counter module could be used such that as the counter increments to a specific binary sequence that takes the same amount of a second. However, I'm not sure how long in binary it takes for a second and in my lab manual it talks about oscillating frequency but I have no idea how to implement that in Verilog. I'm also sure that 1 Hz = 1 second.

Comment: It takes no time whatsoever, unless you tell the tool to make it take time, because Verilog only *models* systems, it is not itself one and does not simulate in real time.  You need to review the basic materials on verilog applicable to your course.

Comment: Traditionally you generate a clock using the delay operator and then count periods of that (or if you prefer to think of it a state machine)

Comment: 1Hz = 1s is wrong. 1Hz = 1s⁻¹.

Answer (score 1):

A timer needs a reference, which is normally a clock signal in the system.

Most systems have one basic clock (a crystal) connected to an pin. This clock is used to generate all other clocks. This can be through dividers or the system can have a PLL.

For your timer find out what clock frequency (frequencies?) you have available. This should be in the lab instructions or in the datasheet of the system you have been given. From that you can calculate how big your divider (counter) should be to get 1 Hz.

You should then use the Verilog delay construction `#...` to make a clock with the same frequency in your test bench.

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
LOCALPARAM CLK_PERIOD= 52.083; // 19.2 MHz clock 

// Generate clock.
initial
begin
   clk = 1'b0;
   forever
      #(CLK_PERIOD/2) clk = ~clk;
end
```

Comment: The internal clock has a frequency of 25 MHz according to the lab manual. How can I use this oscillation frequency to calculate for the binary digits for 1 second?

Comment: @Code4life If it increments 25 million times per second, then you tell me, how many times will it increment in 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

> The internal clock has a frequency of 25 MHz............binary digits for 1 second

The time period for 25 MHz clock is 40ns(1/25MHz). 
The terminal count for the counter will be 1second/40ns. Write a logic in which for every time the counter becomes this big value, you output a tick.